# How best to pull the name of column header into a cell if certain conditions are met across multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2019

Basically, I have an excel sheet similar to the below. I want to use the YES cells to create an equation for the source column which indicates the source of the yeses.

| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YES | NO | NO | Header 1 |
| NO | YES | NO | Header 2 |
| NO | YES | YES | Header 2 and Header 3 |

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: This should work if you are using MS365 `=TEXTJOIN(" and ",,FILTER($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2="YES"))`

Comment: Perhaps if you are not using MS365, and there are only three columns to create an equation for source column then , `=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),COLUMN(A1)))&IFERROR(" and "&INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),COLUMN(B1))),"")&IFERROR(" and "&INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),COLUMN(C1))),"")` but its a bit ugly formula.

Comment: @BigBen Standard - 2019

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Any ideas for a simpler formula?

Comment: This works with Excel 2019, `=TEXTJOIN(" and ",,IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),{1,2,3})),""))` you need to keyed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` . Note assuming you have three columns if its more than that, then just change those {1,2,3} to `COLUMN(A1:Z1)`

Answer (score 2):

For 2019, use some alternative approaches.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" and ",,REPT($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2="YES"))
```

---

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2="YES")),", ",
" and ",IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"YES")-1=0,"1",COUNTIF(A2:C2,"YES")-1))
```

---

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" and ",,IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(
COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),COLUMN(A1:Z1))),""))
```

Need to press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

---

Edit, replacing the last comma with and, which will be the right thing to use,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(
INDEX($A$1:$C$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(
COLUMN($A2:$C2)-COLUMN($A2)+1)/($A2:$C2="YES"),COLUMN(A1:Z1))),"")),", "," and ",
IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"YES")-1=0,"1",COUNTIF(
A2:C2,"YES")-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Excel 2019, try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" and ",,IF(A2:C2="YES",A$1:C$1,""))
```

Confirm through CSE and drag down.

---

Or;

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(A2:C2="YES",A$1:C$1,"")),", "," and ",MAX(1,COUNTIF(A2:C2,"YES")-1))
```

[image]